# How to display html page when server requesting?

Tags: java, html, httpurlconnection

I have a problem with showing html page form localhost. Here is my method but I just get `System.out.println("IN !")` in loop (eclipse console). When I'm putting `http://localhost:1600/myWebPage.html` adress in my browser nothing happened. I'm wondering how to show web page or just some text in browser after typing `http://localhost:1600/myWebPage.html`. Is this path correct ?

```
public class ServerWWW {

    //localhost:1600/

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int portServerWww = 1600;
        ServerSocket ss = null;

        try {
            ss = new ServerSocket(portServerWww);
            System.out.println("Server WWW waiting .....");

            while(true) {
                Socket s = ss.accept(); // block
                new ServiceWWW (s).start();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (ss != null) {
                try {
                    ss.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

class ServiceWWW extends Thread {

        private Socket s = null;
        private int counter;

        public ObslugaWWW(Socket s) {
            this.s = s;
        }



     public void run(){
        try {

           System.out.println("IN !"); //Loop
           URL url = new URL("http://localhost:1600/myWebPage.html");
           HttpURLConnection yc = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
           yc.setRequestMethod("GET");
           yc.setDoOutput(true);
           yc.connect();

           BufferedReader rd  = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(yc.getInputStream()));
           StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
           String line = "OK";

           while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null){
              sb.append(line + '\n');
           }

           System.out.println(sb.toString());

           yc.disconnect();

           } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
           } catch (IOException e) {
           // TODO Auto-generated catch block
              e.printStackTrace();
           }

        }
}
```

Comment: I'm baffled by your question.  What are you attempting to do here?  It sounds like you're attempting to write a web server from your description, but I have no real clue what your code is trying to achieve.

Comment: I agree with @Kenny. Are you running tomcat?? Where your index.html resides?

Comment: You're right it is server which will listen on 1600 port from browser client. It will response by sending html page.

Comment: C:\Users\mathew\workspace\Server\mypage.html

Comment: I'm afraid you've seriously underestimated how complicated it is going to be to write a web server.  Or maybe you're trolling.  I'll play along a little more, though - what is it you are trying to achieve here?  What is your end goal?  Writing a web server isn't something we'll be able to cover in a single StackOverflow question...

Comment: Main question is how to show html file after request from client browser. I'm asking why my method run() just showing me "IN" in loop and why it doesn't show me any text or html page in browser after request.